# How do I cursor paginate (skip and limit after a specific ID) using aggregation in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

Instead of using $skip and $limit to jump to an index #, I'd like to skip past a specified _id using aggregate().

Example: let's say I have a list of items that are sorted by date. The first result would be limited by 10. The second query would take in the last _id of the previous result and skip past that _id. Is that possible?

Comment: If they are sorted by id, you can use `db.collection.find({ _id: {$gt: ObjectId("someid")}})`. But if you want to sort by another field, e.g date, then it's probably not possible to skip by _id without fetching all the data again and looping through it programmatically.

Comment: Check out this blog post, which explains a method of pagination in detail https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1